# Condition for martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

What are the conditions for the function that is two times differentiable and all partial derivatives existing $f$: $$f(B(t)^2,t)$$ to be a martingale?

I am able to show the conditions for $f(B(t),t)$ to be a martingale: this requires that $1/2f_{xx}(B(t),t)$ and $f_t(B(t),t))$ have to be zero, to ensure we don't have $dt$ terms. But how does it work for $f(B(t)^2,t)$?

Comment: For $f(B_t, t)$ you actually just require that $f_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{xx} = 0$, not that both of these terms are individually zero.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_t = B_t^2$, so that by Itô's lemma we have $$dX_t = dt + 2B_t dB_t$$ For $f \in C^{2,1}$, we set $Z_t = f(X_t, t) = f(B_t^2,t)$ and apply Itô's lemma again to get:
$$\begin{align*}
dZ_t &= f_t(X_t, t) dt + f_x(X_t, t) dX_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(X_t, t)(dX_t)^2 \\
&= \left( f_t(X_t, t) + 2X_t f_{xx}(X_t, t) + f_x(X_t, t) \right) dt  + 2B_tf_x(X_t, t) dB_t \\
&= \left( f_t(B_t^2, t) + 2B_t^2 f_{xx}(B_t^2, t) + f_x(B_t^2, t) \right) dt  + 2B_tf_x(B_t^2, t) dB_t 
\end{align*}$$

Thus, for $Z_t$ to be driftless, you need $f_t(B_t^2, t) + 2B_t^2 f_{xx}(B_t^2, t) + f_x(B_t^2, t) = 0$, which is a PDE that can be solved for $f$. This guarantees that $Z_t$ is a local martingale. For $Z_t$ to be a true martingale, then a sufficient condition would be that $B_t f_x(B_t^2, t)$ is in $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realize I should make an SDE from $X(t)=B(t)^{2}$ and use that in the ito formula. When knowing that fact, the exercise is very elementary. Again, thank you very much. I appreciate it.